# Acumatica hide branch lookup from menu

Tags: acumatica

Good day

is it possible to remove the branch picker in the top menu(ribbon)?
[image]

We want to give the users access to other branch warehouses only but we don't want them to have access to the branch itself.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that is possible, but if you only want the user to have access to a single branch, they should be limited to a single branch in permissions.  You can then customize to enable access to other branches via **using (new PXReadBranchRestrictedScope())**.

```
public virtual IEnumerable myView()
{
    using (new PXReadBranchRestrictedScope())
    {
        PXResultset<MyDAC> Results = SelectFrom<MyDAC>
            .Where<MyDAC.inventoryID>.IsEqual<InventoryItem.inventoryID.FromCurrent>>
            .View.Select(Base);

        foreach (PXResult<MyDAC> result in Results)
        {
            MyDAC myDAC = result;

            yield return new PXResult<MyDAC>(myDAC); 
        }
    }
}
```

In MyDAC, include a BranchID field decorated with BranchIDAttribute.

```
#region UsrBranchID
[Branch(IsKey = true)]
[PXDefault(typeof(AccessInfo.branchID))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = Messages.FldUsrBranchID)]
public virtual int? UsrBranchID { get; set; }
public abstract class usrBranchID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrBranchID> { }
#endregion
```

The **using (new PXReadBranchRestrictedScope())** will override the branch restriction that normally comes with the user's defined access and return data for all branches.  I have needed to do this only in one place so far, so the modification was not terribly extensive.

You can see more detail from where I had as similar need at [How do I return data for other branches for a user with access to only one branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58980178/how-do-i-return-data-for-other-branches-for-a-user-with-access-to-only-one-branc)

Comment: This is never interesting thanks for the information.